# When subclassing SKNode, should the Frame property return a non-empty value?

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, sknode

I'm subclassing `SKNode` to render a map that consists of many `SKSpriteNodes` by adding those nodes to my subclass.

All is working well but I noticed that the `Frame` of my node subclass is always 0.

I couldn't find anything about this in the docs, so: am I supposed to override the `Frame`property and return a correct value?

Comment: Can you clarify 'Frame ... Is always 0'? Frame should be a CGRect struct so can't be zero. Usually for an SKNode the frame will have a valid position but zero width and height. If it itself is positioned at 0,0 in the scene then all its members will be zero. That would be normal and no need to override frame. If you want the frame of its children then use the method calculateAccumulatedFrame.

Comment: I mean 0 for both width and height. I noticed that an SKSpriteNode has a valid width and height.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The frame property is the frame of the node itself, ignoring any children. For an SKNode this is a position but zero width and height.

> The frame is non-empty if the node’s class draws content.
>   (https://developer.apple.com/reference/spritekit/sknode)

Which I read as: SKNode draws no content so it is correct for it to be empty.

The frame of the node **and** its children is provided by the method [calculateAccumulatedFrame()](https://developer.apple.com/reference/spritekit/sknode/1483066-calculateaccumulatedframe) and functions that need the frame of the sub-tree *should* call that and not reference the frame property.

So there *should* be no need to override frame for your SKNode. I never have, have similar constructs in a few apps 
and have not yet had problems...

Comment: Makes sense. What would be an example of a node that "draws content"?

Comment: @Krumelur: An SKSpriteNode or an SKLabelNode - both inherit from SKNode but have drawable content so will have width and height according to that content.